# Taillwind Installation Issues

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to install Tailwind on my React project.
I followed the instructions on https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app and I'm using Windows10.
I tried to apply the color but it's not working.
My guess is that the codes below for index.css is wrong.
I get this orange wavy line under @tailwind and when I hover it, it says "Unknown rules @ tailwind".
I appreciate if anyone can help with this issue.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

[image]

Here are my codes.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

App.js

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1 class="text-3xl text-red font-bold underline">
      Hello!
    </h1>
  </div>
```

Thank you!

Screenshot added after posted.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing the `index.css` file anywhere, either in your `index.html` or directly in the `App.js` file? If you are not, then add either:

#### App.js

```js
import "../styles/index.css"
```

#### index.html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/index.css" />
```

This should fix your issue, assuming there are no other errors present.

Comment: Sorry, I should've posted a picture of my files. I just added one above. I've added import './index.css'; on index.js but should it be on App.js?

Comment: @codeEms Assuming the `index.js` file is responsible for creating your root React element, it should work without an issue. That forces React to import the tailwind CSS on each page that you would route to after the fact.

Comment: Just started learning React and I wasn't sure but I do now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Install `Tailwind CSS IntelliSense` Extension to `VS Code` and follow the instructions then the warning will be gone -

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss

Answer (score 0):

are you correct in the index.css path?

Add the @tailwind directives for each of Tailwind's layers to your

```
./src/index.css file.
```

and try to install PostCss Language Support

VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csstools.postcss

Comment: I added another screenshot of my files above.  It's in the same layer so I added import './index.css'; and wavy orange is gone but the color and others are not applied.

Comment: try to add this in terminal   `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`

Comment: and try to install TailwindCSS intelesense in your Vscode extension

Comment: Thanks, I will. I want to double check but was it `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/index.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch` ?

Comment: Yes, you can try it first, who knows if it works

Comment: It worked finally. I had to update my Node.js for this. Thank you!

Comment: ok glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer by [Ridwan Malik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14129810/ridwan-malik) was right but not straight enough. To put it straight, just simply do:

1. Install [Tailwind CSS Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) plugin.
2. Create a `.vscode` directory in root directory and a `settings.json` file under the `.vscode` directory.

   [image: VS Code Screenshot]

3) Add the following snippet to your `settings.json` file.
`json { "files.associations": { "*.css": "tailwindcss" } }` 
And you're set!

**Helpful tip:** Add this to your `settings.json` as well to get suggestions while writing tailwindCSS in your `.css` file.

```json
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "strings": "on"
}
```